# How to select option in "Configuration grub-pc" menu

Tags: grub2, upgrade, mint

I would like to select /dev/sda in the "Configuration grub-pc" menu that popped up in my terminal while upgrading my distro version. However, I have no idea how to select it! Every key I press either does nothing, or takes me to a second menu that says "You chose not to install GRUB to any devices." How do I select it? [image: Configuration grub-pc menu]

When I select `<Ok>` without selecting an option: [image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [tab] to switch between options, use [spacebar] to select.

Comment: This works, why the spacebar to select though? The dialog doesn't indicate that, did I miss it on an earlier screen?

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) simply pressing 'up' and 'down' allows you to move through the options but, yes, 'Space-bar' actually makes the selection by appending an '*' to an option on a list.

Comment: Upgrading from 18.04 (Lubuntu), the Tab key, or the up and down arrows, moves a red indicator box up or down the drive options for the Grub location. However, it is the Space Bar that places the star symbol "*" to designate your selection. (Kind of a double-step selection.) Finally, press the Enter key to continue the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Try <kbd>Tab</kbd> key,it would help you to select the options.

Select continue without installing grub,and then update your grub by running below command,

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hitting tab just highlights the `<Ok>` option, leaving the three options blank.

Comment: press `<ok>`to install grub all of them.So that no option to select which device.

Comment: Read the third paragraph in the screenshot.

Comment: I only want to select the first option. See the second screenshot.

Comment: if you press <no> on the second screenshot,it will take you to the first one.

Comment: @kelorek i tried it,shows the same problem.Then select the continue without installing grub option and update your grub via terminal.My answer also works.

Comment: I followed your instructions when upgrading Pop_OS! 19.10 and was able to successfully reboot without issue. According to the terminal, the  `sudo update-grub` command performs the same actions as APT does immediately after exiting the grub-pc configuration screen (after having opted to take no action), so I'd guess that running `sudo update-grub` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, it's not intuitive... You have to hit the SPACEBAR to select the option so it turns into an asterisk (*). You can't just hit enter without the * even though it lets you. If you do it means you didn't select anything which is why it says "you chose not to install"...